# Jquery if else statement not changing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is something silly, but I cannot find out why this clicked variable **is not changing to true** **after** the arrow has been clicked. I am using jQuery here.

```
var clicked = false;
if (!clicked){
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked');
        clicked = true;
    });
}else {
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked again');
    });
}
```

Live Example (also as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vg6jzhnd/3/)):

```js
var clicked = false;
if (!clicked){
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked');
        clicked = true;
    // end
    });
}else {
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked again');
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-1 team_padding">
<p id="click">click me</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `alert` stops the execution. So you will have to close the alert so that it sets the variable. Also just use a single click handler. And the if block should be moved to inside the handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, but that doesn't change the event handler you've hooked up. The next click just runs the same handler again (the one in the `if` block), because the code you've shown is only run **once**, setting up **one** handler. Proof:

```js
var clicked = false;
if (!clicked){
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked');
        clicked = true;
    });
}else {
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked again');
    });
}
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("clicked = ", clicked);
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 10000);
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-1 team_padding">
<p id="click">click me</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead, move the conditional logic into the handler:

```
var clicked = false;
$('#click').on('click', function(){
    if (!clicked) {
        alert('clicked');
        clicked = true;
    } else {
        alert('clicked again');
    }
});
```

Example:

```js
var clicked = false;
$('#click').on('click', function(){
    if (!clicked) {
        alert('clicked');
        clicked = true;
    } else {
        alert('clicked again');
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-1 team_padding">
<p id="click">click me</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So you're saying that my code was basically just resetting so the change in the var meant nothing right? I suppose your version makes more sense logically too.

Comment: @Jiroscopes: The overall code runs just once, but the code in the event handler (the function you pass into `on`) is run every time the event occurs. So with your original code, it ran just once and hooked up the first handler, which was setting the variable, but then as you say nothing else was changing. With the change above, the code that checks the variable and decides what to do gets run every time the event occurs (e.g., every click).